# I am trying to get the notes json from express server using angular but results into http error. (Angular 14)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am unable to delete a note from my angular app. I am always getting an http error with status code unkonwn.

[image]

Here's my angular code:

### Delete the note service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Note } from 'src/interfaces/notes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotesService {
  apiURL = "***"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNotes(): Observable<Note[]> {
    return this.http.get<Note[]>(this.apiURL)
  }

  deleteNote(note: Note): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.apiURL}/delete/${note.id}`)
  }
}
```

And my express server handling the notes api

```js
const express = require('express');
const Notes = require('../models/Notes');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const notes = await Notes.find({});
    res.status(200).json(notes)
})

router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let success = false;

    const note = await Notes.findById(id);

    if (note) {
        success = true;
        await Notes.findByIdAndDelete(id)
        res.status(200).json({ success })
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({ success })
    }

})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you checked that your API server is running/hosted?

Comment: it seems that noone is listening on localhost:3000.

Comment: That's my route in expressjs. The actual server.js file is elsewhere in the project.